# How to clear off edittext hint value for the next time?

Tags: java, android

In my app,I have a value entered which shown as  hint on my edittext ,where it is calculated from each selection of  item price by user...so it depends on how the user selected specific items and its corresponding  price.but the issue is if the user selected an item the price shown in edittext,thereby again select the other items means the previous value is still existing or showing,not clearing anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [setHint("")](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29) on the edit text whenever selection changes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should set a hint on the editText. The question is not very clear. But if you don't want a hint, and want to set a value to editText, just change the value of editText based on the items selected by user by setting onClickListener on the object and change the value from the Java side. So, in simple words:
1. Set a default hint
2. If hint is not what you want, and you want a value, set the default value on XML side and modify it using Java's side by using onClickListeners on different objects and change the value of editText.

And if this is nothing what you want, please clarify the question.